# Safe to delete files in /storage/emulated/media/logs?

Tags: file-system, file-management, files, logging, android-11

My phone is running out of free space. When Settings > Storage displayedmore than 30GB used by "System", I looked into it further using the DiskUsage Android app.

It told me that  /storage/emulated/media/logs was more than 8GB:

[image: DiskUsage storage diagram]

In this folder were many 256MB log files.

But when I try to view more information about these files in a browser app, no files are displayed. I assume they are protected in some way. I'm not rooted, so maybe they're unavailable for that reason.

Are these files safe to delete, and if yes, can I delete them without rooting?